# emmet.extensionPath custom snippet for javascript file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I am trying to create a custom snippet for javascript file.

I created a **snippets.json** file with the following content

```
{
    "js" : {
        "abbreviations" : {
            "fnrr" : "function (req, res) {\n${cursor}\n}",
            "fnrrn": "function (req, res, next) {\n${cursor}\n}"
        }
    }
}
```

I saved this file to a local directory, say **D:\DevSettings**

Now in the user settings I add the following key-value

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "D:\\DevSettings\\snippets.json"
```

I then reloaded the Visual Studio Code.

Now when I type **fnrr** and press TAB, nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create snippets this way:

<kbd>F1</kbd> "osn" => Preferences: Open User Snippets =>"jas" => javascript

Append to this file:

```
"fnnr": {
    "prefix": "fnrr",
    "body": [
        "function (req, res) {",
        "\t$1",
        "}"
    ]
},
"fnrrn": {
    "prefix": "fnrrn",
    "body": [
        "function (req, res, next) {",
        "\t$1",
        "}"
    ]
},
```

Reload not needed.

Comment: I did this but when I type **fnrr**, in the intellisense the snippet appears at the bottom. See [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7021835/25930596/f26b85ce-35bb-11e7-963e-85587fe91760.png). I need an option to press TAB and it should expand instead of scrolling down the list each time.

Comment: user settings => "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",